# How to convert Address string to AccountId in ink!

Tags: ink

- I want to convert the address string received as a parameter to an ink! AccountId.
- I have implemented the following source code using sp-runtime. When I implemented the following in pallet, it worked, but in ink!, the type of AccountId is different and I can't compile it.
- Please tell me how to convert the string address to AccountId in "ink!".

```
        #[inline]
        fn convert_vec_to_accountid(&self, account_vec: Vec<u8>)-> AccountId{ 
          let mut array = [0; 32];
          let bytes = &account_vec[..array.len()]; 
          array.copy_from_slice(bytes);
          let account32: AccountId32 = array.into();
          let mut to32 = AccountId32::as_ref(&account32);
          let to_address : AccountId = AccountId::decode(&mut to32).unwrap_or_default();
          to_address
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to parse a String to an AccountId exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I read the account page on the polkadot wiki and implemented the following logic.
- I've tested it and it's working fine at the moment.
- However, I don't understand enough to explain this structure to someone.
- So be careful when using this logic.
- Or if anyone can give me the correct logic, detailed explanation, please help me.
  https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-accounts

```
        #[inline]
        fn convert_string_to_accountid(&self, account_str: &str)-> AccountId{
            let mut output = vec![0xFF; 35];
            bs58::decode(account_str).into(&mut output).unwrap();
            let cut_address_vec:Vec<_> = output.drain(1..33).collect();
            let mut array = [0; 32];
            let bytes = &cut_address_vec[..array.len()]; 
            array.copy_from_slice(bytes);
            let accountId:AccountId = array.into();
            accountId
        }
```

Comment: I found this github repository. Looking at this, I recognized that my code was more or less correct.https://github.com/polkadot-js/ss58/blob/master/index.js