# How to convert str type to AccountID type?

Tags: polkadot, ink, smart-contract, rust

Personally, while writing the Treasury contract, it was necessary to change the string type to the account ID type. Even if I google how to do it, I can't find a proper solution, so I'm curious what the solution is.

Comment: [go through this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4762/how-to-convert-address-string-to-accountid-in-ink)

Comment: What kinds of the `str`? SS58 or public key in `str`.

Comment: I was looking for the public key. The question above might be the answer. Thanks!